# How can I set unicode name and description to iOS application when publish on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am publishing my new iOS application on iTunes Connect. But my language (Azerbaijani) not in the list of languages.

But name and description of my application contains specific character (small "ə") for [Azerbaijani language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_language).

> How can I add this character to application name, description and
>   keywords on iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any character you want in iTunes Connect input fields. It does not validate the language. Choose as another language as the app language and just add the keywords and app description in Azerbaijani.

Comment: I tried.  All characters is possible but except small "ə".

Can not insert small "ə".

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste it from somewhere else?

Comment: That means that there is no way to use this character in your app description or name.

Comment: But some apps have this character on its name and description .

For example https://itunes.apple.com/az/app/az-rislam/id500116891?mt=8